# Python build/release system

Tags: python, ant, build-automation

I started using Pyant recenently to do various build/release tasks but have recently discovered that development for this project has ended.

I did some research and can't seem to find any other Python build scripts that are comparable. Just wondering if anyone can recommend one? I basically need it to do what ANT does - do SVN updates, move/copy files, archive etc using an XML file.

Thanks,
g

Comment: You require the build script to be an XML file, right?

Comment: f3lix - XML, not necessarily. I'm used to ANT so XML is fine but I'm open to suggestions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the best answer is to use Ant as-is... that is, use the Java version.  My second suggestion would be to use [scons](http://www.scons.org/).  It won't take much time using scons before you're asking, "Who ever thought of using XML to script a build?"

Comment: I haven't used scons, but I agree that using XML to script builds is a pain. We have our own python-based system that uses XML build config, and we also use Ant. Of the two, Ant is better, but XML still sucks as a build script.

Answer (score 2):

Its not completely comparable but I tend to use [fabric](http://www.nongnu.org/fab/). Its more geared towards deployment with support for ssh to production host and runing things as root there etc.

Answer (score 2):

Some people use [Paver](http://www.blueskyonmars.com/projects/paver/) for build/deployment of Python packages. While I know it works, it does not appeal to me that much.

Answer (score 0):

what about maven? (http://maven.apache.org/) With the right plugins it can do much more then ant, it can even use ant for building if you configure it so.

It's very flexible and supports the full product life cycle. I really recommend you take a look at it.